# iOS 11.4 Not drawing CGImage

Tags: ios, core-animation

My app works on iOS 11.3 but not 11.4.  It renders partially but not fully.
I've looked at my code and can't find any specific thing that is going wrong.
I only have the following log line:

```
2018-06-13 21:34:40.637820-0400 XXXXXXXX[5108:1788561] [Render] CoreAnimation: data provider size is too small
```

I don't log this in my app or any of my dependent libraries.  These log lins only appear in iOS 11.4.

Comment: Try to add environment variable CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 to make a stack trace visible in the log. You can create and via the build scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with how I was calling `CGImageCreate` My old code looked like this:
    CGImageRef shapeRef = nil;

```
ShapeSurface* s; //init happens elsewhere in C++ code

CGDataProviderRef dataRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(s, s->pBitmap,
                                                         s->width * s->height * 4,
                                                         ReleaseCGShapeCallback);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

shapeRef = CGImageCreate(s->width,
                         s->height,
                         8,                     // bits per component (byte)
                         4 * 8,                 // bits per pixel (4 bytes per pixel, 8 bits per pyte)
                         s->width,              // bytes per row
                         colorSpace,            // image color space
                         kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst,
                                                // surfaces are argb little-endian
                         dataRef,               // data provider for the raw image
                         NULL,                  // no decoder
                         false,                 // no interpolation
                         kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataRef);
```

This line was changed:

```
                         s->width * 4,         // bytes per row
```

The bytes per row calculation is now correct.  I don't know why the previous versions of iOS this worked and now suddenly stopped.